# show all images of a product in slider using flutter and woocommerce API

Tags: woocommerce, flutter, woocommerce-rest-api, flutter-test

I'm working in e-commerce mobile application using flutter where i have to show information about my products .

OK my code is working perfectly but it gives me just one image for each product,
so I want to know if there is a way to show all pictures of each product .

Comment: Welcome to SO Asma! You will have to provide some code for us to look at before we can help you.

Comment: please add some code...

Comment: You just need to change it to show more images.

Comment: This gives me the possibility to get one image but i need something that get all images for each product 

 final String image=posts[index]["images"][0]["src"];

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Just use swiper.... Eg:

```
 Swiper(
                itemCount: widget.product.images.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Image.network(
                    widget.product.images[index].src,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    height: double.infinity,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                  );
                },
                pagination: new SwiperPagination(),
                control: new SwiperControl(),
              ),
```